# Find last but one element in #each helper in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, each

In my ember application I've a scenario where I want to display the last but one element of an array in a different way.

```
{{#each item in model}}
   {{#if lastButOneItem}}
      + {{item}}
   {{else}}
      {{item}} +
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

But I'm not sure how to put the condition for the lastButOneItem. Is there a simple way to achieve it ?

I tried assigning an ItemController for this. But I can't get the total number of elements from that item controller and the current index.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various approaches in Ember to this old problem, but it's probably easiest to handle it at the CSS level:

```
{{#each item in model}}
   <span class="item">{{item}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

```css
.item                   ::after  { content: " + "; }
.item:nth-last-child(2) ::after  { content: "";    }
.item:nth-last-child(2) ::before { content: " + "; }
```

The alternative would be to build an array of strings in your controller or view or component:

```js
displayItems: function() {
    var model = this.get('model');
    var len   = model.length;

    return model.map(function(item, idx) {
        return idx === len - 2 ? " + " + item : item + " + ";
    });
} . property('model.@each')
```

```html
{{#each item in displayItems}}
  {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the workarounds. The second one seems more comfortable.